# how to make a script that keeps searching the internet for a specific filetype?

Tags: php, database

i want to make a big database of MP3s . for that i need a software or a script that keeps searching for songs and adds them to a database. such script must have already been created by someone. where can i get it ? or how to make one in php?
or is there any existing open database of songs available for download?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very large [music data base](http://musicbrainz.org/)
But just so you know, you can't just get mp3 for free, in other words thats illegal, you can have playlists and such. and you should look around musicbrainz.org, you will find what you need